# How do I handle Page Refresh with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I just followed the setup from http://scotch.io/bar-talk/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

This tutorial introduced controllers and services with angular.js for a single-page app..

When I directly visit /pageName, or click the anchor-link for the /pageName route and then press the browser 'Refresh', the page displays:

```
Error: ENOENT, stat './public/views/index.html'
```

After reading some answers to similar questions, I changed:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html');
});
```

to:

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
```

..though now the result is `Error: ENOENT, stat '/app/app/public/views/index.html'`

Comment: What's the correct full path to index.html?

Comment: /Users/username/appMainFolder/public/index.html on my local comp.. app/public/index.html on heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first of all, your file is in `./public/index.html` , and you are searching in `./public/views/index.html` , try:

```
res.sendfile('./public/index.html');
```

if that doesen't work,try this:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
     res.sendfile('index.html', { root: './public' });
});
```